# Validating Changes to pam.d (like visudo)

Tags: linux, macos, sudo, ansible, pam

I'm working on an Ansible task for setting fingerprint sudo usage in MacOS. This is done through a custom rule in `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local`.

Is there a method to pre-validate edits to PAM for safer automation, as `visudo -c` gives for sudoers? Unfortunately it doesn't appear that `visudo` itself parses PAM  directives.

Ansible provides a `validate:` parameter for pre-validating changes to a file, before it is overwritten. This would be very useful for PAM edits.